# Flat projection in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using an ImageMapType to draw over a custom image using Google Maps API v3.
The problem I'm facing is that when I draw at the lower/upper bounds of the "world" the image gets stretched ... most likely due to the default Mercator projection that the API uses.

How can I change this projection to a flat one ?